# Compute expectation of a random variable given the density function

Tags: self-study, uniform-distribution, continuous-data

The probability density function is given by:

$f(t)= (8-t)^2 /9$ for $5 \le t \le 8$

Compute the mean daily CPU time. Hence state the mean of a new variable $W=T+12$ hours.

For this question, based on the information given, I would think it to be a continuous uniform distribution. I know that the mean is $b+a$.

Also, for the other part, I'm wondering how to make $T$ the subject of the formula so that $T=W-12$ hours and then put that in wherever $T$ is?

Side note, can anyone tell me how to insert actual symbols into the posts (eg. the actual 'beta' symbol and not 'b')?

Comment: You can look at the help for guidance e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting I've added the tag self-study as this appears to be a homework problem or something similar. Hint on the problem: draw the curve for your density function. Is it flat?

Comment: The mean of a continuous uniform distribution $U(a, b)$ is not $a + b$. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to compute ${\rm E}(W)$.
Here are two hints:

1. Use the property of lineary of the expectation to write ${\rm E}(W)$ as a function of $T$ and 12.
2. Compute ${\rm E}(T)$ from the definition of the expectation of a continuous random variable using the density $f(t)$.